# setTimeout with prompt causing incrementing default value

Tags: javascript

Just experimenting with JS. I have found something I cant get my head around.

I have this code:

```js
prompt('title', setTimeout(() => {
    return 'yes'
}, 1000));
```

When I first run it, it prints 2. But when I run it again, it prints 3.

But what is this counter, and why is it starting from 2? Where does the values come from? Why is it not returning yes?

Comment: But how do i make it return yes? Since it goes into the task queue and will execute after the main thread? It will anyways return the counter

Answer (score 2):

When you call `setTimeout` the timeout is given a timeoutID (which can be later used to cancel it with `clearTimeout`). This timeoutID increments whenever a new timeout is made. When setting it as the default value for the `prompt`, it is stringified (causing the timeoutID  to be returned).

The value starts from two because you've probably made a timeout before running the `prompt`.

Demonstration:

```js
const first = setTimeout(() => {}, 1).toString()
const second = setTimeout(() => {}, 1).toString()
console.log(first, second)
```